# Compatibility mode in IE 9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, ie-compatibility-mode

I am looking for solution that will help me to make my web page compatible with IE 7, 8, 9.

I have inherited page, which if rendered in IE 7 there are no issues.
However if I do render it in IE 8,9 the page is not rendered correctly.

I have fixed the page header and content.
But in some cases I still does not render correctly.
I am in process of running the CSS and HTML through W3C validator and removing issues.

Is there some way to tell me why the page has been run under compatibility mode and what are the issues?

**Update**
I have in the system html header:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

which is defined here: http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

As html5 is not yet standard, I am not sure whether it is good for me to use that and after fight older versions of IE

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen: true is that the page has been updated last: 2011/12/16 02:56:49

Comment: Just has been digging bit deeper and found another draft on w3c so not sure what make of it: http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-diff-20121025/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me is:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you included the `doctype`? Leaving out the doctype forces IE to render the page in compatibility mode. Throw in the HTML5 doctype at the top and see what happens

`<!DOCTYPE html>`